# Where can I find the full recording of The Siamese Cat song from Lady and the Tramp?

Tags: recording, song-title, songwriter

I first heard this song back in 2004 when a friend gave me a tape with a Disney readalong on a cassette, with Lady and the Tramp being on one side, and another book on the other.
It wasn't until the end of the book that I heard this weird duet, but I didn't actually learn what it was until I watched the full film in 2013.

After listening to the song, I realised that the film version is missing two entire versus up until you get to

```
We come in on this domicile.
```

Upon reading the lyrics on Google's knowledge result, I tried looking for the full version, but so far I haven't found anything. The only thing I found was [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wyHP9b7RK6Q), which is actually quite interesting.

Comment: The song in the movie is already more than long enough, the other verses were probably never recorded.

Comment: If they were never recorded, how is it that Google has record of it?

Comment: The scene as originally conceived might have been longer, so lyrics would have been written. The music would have been recorded very late in the production process after the scene had been shortened. Maybe the google hit comes from the Disney archives.